# All files in an array not converting to base64 in react js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, base64

I have a custom hook called useBase64 where I convert my image to Base64. This hook accepts an initial value and returns handleCreateBase64 function and logo (piece of state). handleCreateBase64 converts the file to base64 and stores it in logo. I am sending an array of images as File and then mapping through that array and I want to store it in logo and then send it to that component. right now the problem is that in the logo I can only see 1 base64 even if I select multiple files.

useBase64 hook: -

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

export const useBase64 = (initialValue) => {
const [logo, setLogo] = useState(initialValue)

const handleCreateBase64 = useCallback(async (receivedFile) => {
    let file = receivedFile;

    if(initialValue instanceof Array) {
      file = Object.values(receivedFile)

     file.map(async el => {
        const base64 = await convertToBase64(el)
        setLogo([...logo, base64])
    }) 
    }
  });

  const convertToBase64 = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      if (!file) {
        console.log("no image");
      } else {
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        fileReader.onload = () => {
          resolve(fileReader.result);
        };
      }
      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });
  };

return { handleCreateBase64, logo }
```

}

The result: -

[image]

As you can see above that I have 3 images selected but I see only 1 base64. I am quiet new to this so it will be great if full explanation is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong use of map and setState

Try:

```
const items = await Promise.all(file.map(el => convertToBase64(el)))
setLogo([...logo, ...items])
```